# Add two numbers and display result without clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make a simple form that allows the user to add two numbers and I want it to show the total number once both of them are added without clicking any button or without page refresh

```js
function add_number() {
                   
  var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text1").value);
  var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text2").value);
  var result = first_number + second_number;

  document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Enter First Number :</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Text1" name="TextBox1">
<br> <p>Enter Second Number :</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Text2" name="TextBox2">
<br>Result :
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtresult" name="TextBox3">
```

I tried the above code but it is not working.

Comment: You need to add an event handler. Right now you've written a function that is never called. You likely want to call it on `keyup` or `keydown` of your inputs.

Comment: Actually, rather than using `keyup` or `keydown` event, I'd recommend the `input` event each input element will emit whenever its value changes. Secondly, why not use `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt`, because then you can add non-integer numbers too. Thirdly, do something like `var text1 = document.getElementById("Text1")` *outside* of the `add_number` function ONCE, rather than searching your HTML every single time you call `add_number` to find the same elements over and over again.

Comment: @kshetline *"I'd recommend the input event"* - it's too late for me to edit my comment but I agree with you here. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

I was writing this as @TylerRoper and @kshetline made their useful comments, so I've incorporated them. Fundamentally what was needed was to add the event handler. I've also included a check for the parse failing so that you get a result even if one field is empty or non-numeric (it's treated as 0).

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById("Text1");
var text2 = document.getElementById("Text2");

function add_number() {
   var first_number = parseFloat(text1.value);
   if (isNaN(first_number)) first_number = 0;
   var second_number = parseFloat(text2.value);
   if (isNaN(second_number)) second_number = 0;
   var result = first_number + second_number;
   document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter First Number :</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Text1" name="TextBox1" oninput="add_number()">
<br> <p>Enter Second Number :</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Text2" name="TextBox2" oninput="add_number()">
<br>Result :
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtresult" name="TextBox3">
```

Comment: i try to add it in PHP query but unfortunately is the first column that is working how would i fixed it?

Comment: @abbagana I'm sorry I don't understand your comment. What does PHP and queries have to do with this question?

Comment: I added the request in the comment

Answer (score 1):

Good solution provided by @Nick. I just added a check that user can enter only numeric input. An alternative approach.

```js
function add_number(e) {
  if (isNumberKey(e)) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var first_number = document.getElementById("Text1").value !== "" ? parseInt(document.getElementById("Text1").value) : 0;
      var second_number = document.getElementById("Text2").value !== "" ? parseInt(document.getElementById("Text2").value) : 0;
      var result = first_number + second_number;
      document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
    }, 50)
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter First Number : <input type="text" id="Text1" name="TextBox1" onkeypress="return add_number(event)"></p>

<p>Enter Second Number : <input type="text" id="Text2" name="TextBox2" onkeypress="return add_number(event)"></p>

<br>Result : <input type="text" id="txtresult" name="TextBox3">
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i try to add it in PHP query but unfortunately is the first column that is working how would i fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery approach:

```js
$('#Text1, #Text2').on("paste keyup",

  function () {
  
    var result = parseInt($("#Text1").val()) + parseInt($("#Text2").val());
    
    $("#txtresult").val((isNaN(result) ? '' : result));
    
  }
  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enter First Number:</p>
<input type="text" id="Text1" name="TextBox1">
<p>Enter Second Number:</p>
<input type="text" id="Text2" name="TextBox2">
<p>Result:</p>
<input type="text" id="txtresult" name="TextBox3">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add_number() {
                   
  var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text1").value);
  var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text2").value);
  var result = first_number + second_number;

  document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Enter First Number :</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Text1" name="TextBox1">
<br> <p>Enter Second Number :</p>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Text2" name="TextBox2">
<br>Result :
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtresult" name="TextBox3">
<p>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="add_number()">
<input type="reset" value="reset">
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.